# php calculate age from birth date html form

Tags: php, html, forms, date

I am looking for a way to calculate the age when the user enter his birth date in html form and press the submit button. I saw similar questions but they all about calculating already existing age but here I am talking about entering date and then calculating the age.

I tried to make the code but it gives me wrong age:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">   

Enter your date of birth:
<select name="month" >
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>

</select>
<select name="day" id="day">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year">
<option value="1">2013</option>
<option value="2">2012</option>
<option value="3">2011</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="age" >


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$year = $_POST['year'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
if ($year != '' && $month != '' && $day != '') {
$birthDate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;

$age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[2], $birthDate[1],  $birthDate[0]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$birthDate[0])-1):(date("Y")-$birthDate[0]));
echo "Age is: ".$age;
}}
?>
```

Comment: $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[2], $birthDate[1],  $birthDate[0]) ?????    $birthdate is not an array. How do you expect this to work?

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: <option value="1">Month</option> <-- and what's this??? a new month in the Gregorian calendar year???

Comment: Why not leverage existing PHP functions to subtract your dates? http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Comment: Why not write it in Javascript and give your server a break?!

Comment: What about leap years!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date is a string and you try to calculate using it , try first to parse string to date :

```
$birthDate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;

$time = strtotime($birthDate);

$birthDate= date('Y-m-d',$time);
```

also close `</form>`

Answer (score 0):

simple php code to calculate age from date of birth

```
$Age = ((time()- strtotime ($dateofbirth))  /(3600 * 24 * 365))
```